# Scaling generated paths to same size as SVG paths loaded into in matter-js

Tags: d3.js, matter.js

I am loading a saved svg (created in illustrator) using d3 into a pre-named div. The div also contains a canvas element using the following;

```
d3.xml("moniac.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function (error, xml) {
    if (error) throw error;
    document.getElementById('moniac').appendChild(xml.documentElement);
```

I then set up my matter.js physics engine and add an event listener so that when the svg resizes then so does the canvas in proportion. So far so good.

```
const myCanvas = document.getElementById('water');
    const {
        clientWidth: width,
        clientHeight: height,
      } = document.querySelector('#moniac svg');
    const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
    const world = engine.world;
    const Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
    const Composites = Matter.Composites;
    const Common = Matter.Common;
    const Svg = Matter.Svg;
    const Vertices = Matter.Vertices;
    const render = Matter.Render.create({
    canvas: myCanvas,
    engine,
    options: {
      width,
      height,
      background: 'transparent',
      wireframes: false,
      showAngleIndicator: false,
    },
    });
```

I then select a particular group of paths and polygons from the loaded svg withing a g element called 'shape' and pass them through a function to create matter.js static vertices using the following

```
    let paths = d3.select('#shape').selectAll('polygon')._groups[0];
    console.log ('polygons', paths )
    const vertex = [];
    paths.forEach((path) => {
      const vertices = d3.select(path).attr('points');
      let newShape = Matter.Vertices.fromPath(vertices);
      vertex.push(Vertices.scale(newShape, 1, 1))
    })


    paths = d3.select('#shape').selectAll('path')._groups[0];
    paths.forEach((path) => {
      const NUM_POINTS = 200
      let points = [];
      let len = path.getTotalLength();
      for (var i=0; i<=NUM_POINTS-1; i++) {
        let pt = path.getPointAtLength(i * len / (NUM_POINTS -1));
        points.push(pt.x, pt.y);
      }
      let newShape = Matter.Vertices.fromPath(String(points));
      vertex.push(newShape)
    })
    let newVertices = Matter.Bodies.fromVertices(width/2, height/2, vertex,{isStatic: true});
    Matter.World.add(world, newVertices);
```

...and this is where the problem seems to be coming in as the new vertices I've created are not scaled to the same position as the svg paths they were created from and I'm a bit stuck as to how I'd do this as I'm a bit new to matter.js. Do I apply a scale from the resize function or is that completely wrong?. This is what I currently have, the black lines are the created vertices and the white is the loaded svg:

[image: Depiction of the scaling/translation issue described]